# Use REGEXP_REPLACE for replacing a string between quote

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb, regexp-replace

Use of REGEXP_REPLACE in MySQL/Maria DB for replacing "City 'ABCDE' not found" in "City %PARAM% not found"

Hi,

Someone can help me with the use of REGEXP_REPLACE in MySQL/Maria DB ?

I have a table with a column "message" with the value :

- City 'ABCDE' not found
- City 'ABCDEFGH' not found
- City 'AB' not found
- City 'ABCDEFG HIJ KLM' not found

I want to replace all string between ' by the string %PARAM% :

- City %PARAM% not found
- City %PARAM% not found
- City %PARAM% not found
- City %PARAM% not found

But I failed with the use of regex :(

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consecutive Pattern replacing is not happening with REGEXP\_REPLACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701025/consecutive-pattern-replacing-is-not-happening-with-regexp-replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following update query:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET message = REGEXP_REPLACE(message, '''.*?''', '%PARAM%')
WHERE message LIKE '%''%''%';
```